# Check if returned value is integer or char

Tags: c++

I have a little "blackjack" program coded in C++. The thing is that the program asks questions like "Would you like... (y/n)?" where user needs to type y/n. I want to check if the value returned is actually the type that I want. So function that should return int, returns int and function that should return char, returns char, before it actually returns something.

I would need some suggestions guys. I think it's not that difficult, I just can't find any solution. Thank you.

Code:

```
char pickCard(){
    char aCard;
    std::cout << "Would you like another card?";
    std::cin >> aCard;
    if (aCard is a char){
        return aChar;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not a char!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make sure you only get `y` or `n`?

Comment: well, in this case - yes. But it would be nice to know how to check if the returned value is char or if it's any other type... for the future programming :)

Comment: You have a misconception: your variable `aCard` is always an `int`, never a `char`.  Its value may be among those representable by type `char` (or not), but that's an altogether different question.

Comment: Oops, thanks. I just made a mistake. I'm still looking for answer, tho.

Comment: Are you trying to decide whether it's a *letter* versus a *number*?

Comment: Yeah, for example. I just want to check if the returned thing(value) is a letter or number.

Comment: e.g. like in php ... We can check if the value or variable is string with function is_string($var); .. I'm looking for something similar in C++.

or (lets say) is_int(); - I hope you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @GrafComp.net Those are not standard in C++.  You can make your own though by taking the input in as a string and then parsing it to determine what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misconception of exactly how `std::istream`'s formatted input works.  In your example, `aCard` *must* be a `char`, because you've declared it as such.  If the use enters more than one character, one character will be put into `aCard`, and `std::cin` will hold onto the other characters and give them to you the next time you call `operator>>` (or any other input function); if the user enters a number, `aCard` will be the character representation of the first digit of that number.

Keep in mind that `operator>>` knows what type of variable you've given it, and it will ensure that the user's input is valid for that type.  If you give it an `int`, it will make sure the users input is convertible to an `int` or give you `0` if it isn't.  A variable can never be anything but the type you declared it to be.

If you're interested in `char`s in particular, there's a whole bunch of [character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte) you can use to tell what sort of character (letter, digit, whitespace, etc.) you're working with, but keep in mind that `char foo('4')` is entirely different than `int foo(4)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was useful. You were right I had a misconception on that one.. didn't know that the operator will give value of 0 if we type some char or something else into our int variable.

Comment: If you want to avoid the "`std::cin` will hold onto the other characters and give them to you the next time you call `operator>>` (or any other input function)" behaviour - if you want to be sure that the program pauses every time you "prompt for input" - then always use `std::getline` (free function, *not* the `istream` member function) to read from `std::cin` (a line at a time), and use a `std::stringstream` (from `<sstream>`) to parse it, if necessary. At least, that's what I remember from 2010 or so; there's probably something more sophisticated now...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force y or n as only allowed  characters you can do:

```
char pickCard(){
    std::string response;
    std::cout << "Would you like another card?";
    std::cin >> response;
    if (response=="y" || response=="n"){

        return response[0]; //or anything useful 
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not a char!";
         //... more code here
    }
         //... more code here
}
```

you can use length() property of std::string to find its length. a string of length one is a char in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Yeah, I know that. I'm actually using it right now.

Comment: What I mean is if there is any kind of function to check the actual type of value returned. Just for the future, the code is just an example.

Comment: There is no type reflection system in C++. You'd have to handle it yourself.

Comment: If it's not the right response surely you would want to loop back and try again?

Comment: BTW this function does not return along all exit paths.

Answer (score 0):

I  guess you just want to know if the input string is in number format. `>>` will set the `istream`'s failbit if it cannot convert the input string to `int`.

```
int num;

if (cin >> num) {       // input is "123abc", num == 123
  cout <<  "yes, input is a number. At least start with some figures. "
  cout << "num == " << num;
} else { // input is "abc" , error
  cout << "no, input is not a number or there is some kind of IO error." 

}
```